# Does for loop create a copy of vectors, arrays or any other datatypes in c++?

Tags: c++, for-loop, copy

```
vector<string> names {"Larry", "Moe", "Curly"};

for (auto str: names)     
        str = "Funny";
```

This doesn't change the contents of original vector...

```
for (auto &str: names)  
        str = "Funny";
```

While this does...

So does the for loop create a copy and then loop over that copy ?

Comment: More like the variable gets one copy at a time (or a referencce in second case).

Comment: The first loop binds a value, yes, it copies the values out, which you then change. The second binds a reference, changing that changes what it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first for-loop makes copies of the values, similar to *pass by value*.

The second one takes a *reference* of the values using `&`, which would change the values in its entirety (and not solely inside the loop body), similar to the concept of *pass by reference*.

> So does the for loop create a copy and then loop over that copy ?

For the first one, yes.